# I am trying to implement this interface, but need some help:

Tags: c#

This is the `IEnumerable` interface in which adding some words and returning in last two methods

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Thesaurus {

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a thesaurus.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IThesaurus {
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the given synonyms to the thesaurus
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="synonyms">The synonyms to add.</param>
        void AddSynonyms(IEnumerable < string > synonyms);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the synonyms for a given word.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="word">The word the synonyms of which to get.</param>
        /// <returns>A <see cref="string"/> with all synonyms for the given word.</returns>
        IEnumerable < string > GetSynonyms(string word);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all words from the thesaurus.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerable<string>"/> containing
        /// all the words in the thesaurus.</returns>
        IEnumerable < string > GetWords();
    }
}
```

And here is my code, my problem is the param in the `AddSynonyms` method when I call in `GetSynonyms` and `GetWords` methods, I don't know how to fix it.

```
public class Thesaurus {

    public void AddSynonyms(IEnumerable < string > synonyms) {
        synonyms = new List < string > () {
            "one", "two", "three"
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable < string > GetSynonyms(string word) {
        foreach(String s in AddSynonyms()) {
            if (s == word) {
                yield return s;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable < string > GetWords() {
        foreach(String s in AddSynonyms()) {
            yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `AddSynonyms` takes in an `IEnumerable` and returns void. You're treating it like it is parameterless and returns an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: yes I know, I need AddSynonyms to take IEnumerable because I need to implement the interface as it is

Comment: You're trying to iterate over a method that has a return type of `void`, and your calls of said method have no parameters..

Comment: I would think that you'd want a private field of type `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` to associate words with synonyms.  Then the `AddSynonyms` would add to that and `GetSynonyms` would just do a lookup.  It's not completely clear what `GetWords` should do (return all different words in the thesaurus?), but it doesn't make sense for you to ignore the parameter sent in to `AddSynonyms` or to try to use `AddSynonyms` in a `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my best guest as to how to implement that interface.  Please note you might want to use a different internal data-structure based on how much data is put into the Thesaurus or if you need `AddSynonyms` to be more preformant than `GetSynonyms`.  Additionally there is some error checking and corner cases that might not be handled here, but I hope this at least gives you an idea on how the interface should be implemented.

```
public class Thesaurus : IThesaurus
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> lookup = 
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); 

    public void AddSynonyms(IEnumerable<string> synonyms)
    {
        var words = synonyms.Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            var currentWordSynonyms = words.Where(w => w ! == word).ToList();
            if (lookup.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                foreach (var synonym in currentWordSynonyms)
                {
                    if(!lookup[word].Contains(synonym))
                        lookup[word].Add(synonym);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lookup.Add(word, currentWordSynonyms);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word)
    {
        if(lookup.ContainsKey(word))
            return lookup[word];
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        // Or throw an exception.
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetWords()
    {
        return lookup.Keys();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

The idea here is that you have a `Dicitionary` that will associate each word to a `List` of words that are synonyms.  The `AddSynonyms` method will take an enumeration of synonyms and begin by creating a list of unique words, in case there are any duplicates.  It then goes through each word and checks to see if it has already been added.  If it has then it goes through all the synonyms of that word (the `words` list minus the `word`) and checks to see if they are in the `List` associated with that word.  If not the synonym is added to the list.  If the word is not already in the `Dicitionary` then it is added  along with a `List` of it's synonyms (again the `words` list minus the `word`).

The `GetSynonymns` method then just returns the `List` that is associated with the given `word`.  If the word is not in the Thesaurus then an empty enumeration is returned (you could change that to throw an exception if so desired).

The `GetWords` method simply returns all the keys of the `Dicitionary` which will be every word that was added.

This code will create a lot of duplication as each word will reference a list of synonyms in the `Dicitionary`.  But this will result in the `GetSynonyms` and `GetWords` methods being rather fast.  However `AddSynonyms` would become slower as the internal `Dicitionary` grows.

This does not validate that the parameters sent into the methods are not null.  It also allows you to associate something like "This is a sentence" as a synonym of "123456", so basically any string can be a synonym of any other string.

Comment: Can you givev some explanation pls, Iam very new in c#

Comment: @Sivar I'm updated my answer to include some additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

AddSynonyms(IEnumerable synonyms) is a method that you will not call from GetSynonyms() or GetWords().

The class that implements IThesaurus should maintain a protected property that looks something like this:

```
protected List<ISynonyms> Synonyms {get; set;}

GetSynonyms(string word) and GetWords() should be returning Items from that Property.

AddSynonym(IEnumerable<string> synonyms) will be adding items to that Property.
```

ISynonyms would be a interface that inherits from `IDictionary<string, List<string>>` where the string is the Word you are storing Synonyms for and List are the Synonyms for the Word.  You could also forgo the ISynonyms interface and just have this:

```
protected IDictionary<string, List<string>> {get; set;}
```

Then set this to a new Dictionary>() in the Constructor.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me.  What is `ISynonym`?  If you think there needs to be another interface/class defined you should show what you think it should look like.

Comment: ISynonym would be something like a Dictionary<string, List<string>> where the dictionary Key would be the word you are storing Synonyms for and List<string> would be the Synonyms of the word.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you're intention was to return an IEnumerable in the add synonums method, because your input parameter wasn't even ever being used. So I think you intended on this:

```
public interface IThesaurus
{

        IEnumerable<string> AddSynonyms();
        IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word);

        IEnumerable<string> GetWords();

}
```

You're question wasn't clear, but you need to implement your interface on the class and now you won't get the AddSynonyms error message.

now you can implement the interface:

```
public class Thesaurus : IThesaurus
{
       public IEnumerable<string> AddSynonyms()
       {
          return new List<string>() {"one", "two", "three"};
       }

       public IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word)
       {
           return AddSynonyms().Where(s => s == word);
       }

       public IEnumerable<string> GetWords()
       {
           return AddSynonyms();
       }
}
```

Note that GetWords and AddSynonyms are themselves 'synonymous' :) you should make one of the methods have a different purpose.

Comment: No, the AddSynonyms is void and must take that param in the interface

Comment: IHMO a method called `AddSynonyms` that has a return value and no parameters doesn't make much sense.

Comment: no it doesn't but his code did the same thing: `IEnumerable<string> synonyms` then he immediately sets synonyms without ever using the parameter. `synonyms = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three"};` there it's overwritten doing the exact same thing as the code I wrote

Comment: @Sivar it can't be void and return IEnumerable at the same time, which do you want and why?

Comment: Yes I know I must use the parameter in the return methods, is that possible and how?

Comment: you don't have to return the same parameter that your receive, what you would like to do?

Answer (score -5):

You need write:

```
public class Thesaurus :  IThesaurus
{
public void AddSynonyms(IEnumerable<string> synonyms){

 synonyms = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three"};

}

public IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word){

foreach(String s in AddSynonyms()){

     if(s == word)
        {
         yield return s;
}
  }

public IEnumerable<string> GetWords(){

foreach(String s in AddSynonyms()){

         yield return s;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why? An explanation is totally missing here; this is just code for copy and pasting, which will not help any future visitors with similar problems. In fact, I can only think of *why not*, and that's already covered by [Jon B](http://stackoverflow.com/users/27414/jon-b)'s comment on the question.

Comment: He added `: IThesaurus`, which, true, is necessary. But it's still very broken.

Comment: Yeah - was mean only this art : , I dont check all code((

Comment: If you don't have a complete answer, it should be made in a comment.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Sorry again